# SQL Query - Join on ALL rows of a previous join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:

> 1. pages(id, name, desc)
> 2. page_tags(id, page_id, tag_id)
> 3. tag_posts(tag_id, post_id)

Given a page in the pages table, I want to get the posts in tag_posts table where tag_id matches **ALL** the tag_ids for the given page in the page_tags table.

For instance, if the entries in the 3 tables are:

1) pages:

> 1. [1, 'page 1', 'some desc']

2) page_tags:

> 1. [1, 1, 1],
> 2. [2, 1, 2]

3) tag_posts:

> 1. [1, 101],
> 2. [2, 102],
> 3. [1, 201],
> 4. [3, 202]

I did a simple inner join of the 3 tables using this query:

```
SELECT tp.*
FROM pages p
JOIN page_tags pt ON pt.page_id = p.id
JOIN tag_posts tp ON tp.tag_id = pt.tag_id
WHERE 1
```

However, this returns rows 1, 2 and 3 from the sample tag_posts table above whereas I wanted only rows 1 and 2 as these two rows match **ALL** the tag_id rows from the first join between pages and page_tags table.

Please let me know how I can achieve this. Note: I'm using mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused.  tag_post table does have 3 matches (row 1 2 and 3) because tag_post where tag_id = 1 is matched twice.  So i would say its correct in what you are seeing.

If you are trying to find the tag_posts for a specified page then the query will be this...

```
SELECT tp.*
FROM pages p
JOIN page_tags pt ON pt.page_id = p.id
JOIN tag_posts tp ON tp.tag_id = pt.tag_id
WHERE p.id = 1
```

Comment: My first join is between pages and page_tags and it gives me all tags for a given page. I want the second join to give me posts that match all tags from the first join. I hope I've expressed my requirement clearly.

Comment: Your join is correct.  In your example above, page 1 is referenced twice in the page_tags table.  In English, page 1 has tags with ids 1 and 2.  These tags are referenced 3 times in the tag_posts table.  In the tag_posts table, Row 1 and 3 reference tag 1, and Row 2 references tag 2.  Which is why you get 3 tags for page 1 and not 2 tags.  Let me know if I'm interpreting your tables wrong.